# The MySQL query return an empty set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named `product` from where I would like to retrieve top 3 data within a date range in decreasing order by quantity. My table is provided,

```
# product_id, stock_id, quantity, stock_timestamp
Product ID9, Stock ID2, 1050, 2019-03-04 07:06:37
Product ID8, Stock ID2, 950, 2019-03-04 07:06:27
Product ID7, Stock ID2, 85000, 2019-03-04 07:06:17
Product ID6, Stock ID1, 750, 2019-03-04 07:06:07
Product ID5, Stock ID1, 65000, 2019-03-04 07:05:57
Product ID4, Stock ID1, 550, 2019-03-04 07:05:47
Product ID3, Stock ID, 450, 2019-03-04 07:05:37
Product ID27, Stock ID5, 1950, 2019-02-28 07:05:17
Product ID26, Stock ID5, 1850, 2019-02-28 07:05:17
Product ID25, Stock ID5, 1750, 2019-02-28 07:05:17
Product ID24, Stock ID4, 211650, 2019-02-24 07:05:17
Product ID23, Stock ID4, 1550, 2019-02-24 07:05:17
Product ID22, Stock ID4, 1450, 2019-02-24 07:05:17
```

I write the SQL query as provided,

```
SELECT * FROM StockHandler.product WHERE stock_timestamp BETWEEN  DATE("2019-03-03") AND DATE("2019-03-04")  ORDER BY quantity DESC  LIMIT 3 ;
```

I get an empty value from the returned query. I find no error in the SQL. So, how do I write it correctly?

Comment: Can you post your create syntax for the table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you imagine 'DATE("2019-03-03")' will do

Comment: The problem is solved for now. The table is generated from the Java application, so, I didn't think you were required to post in the question. I will do so in the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below - `date()` for `stock_timestamp`

```
SELECT * FROM StockHandler.product 
WHERE date(stock_timestamp) BETWEEN  '2019-03-03' AND '2019-03-04' 
ORDER BY quantity DESC  LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without date()

```
SELECT * FROM StockHandler.product 
WHERE date(stock_timestamp) BETWEEN  '2019-03-03' AND '2019-03-04' 
ORDER BY quantity DESC  LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Note that this solution cannot use an index

Answer (score 0):

MySql will treat

```
DATE("2019-03-03") AND DATE("2019-03-04")
```

as

```
DATE("2019-03-03 00:00:00") AND DATE("2019-03-04 00:00:00")
```

You can use @fa06's answer or edit the time to

```
DATE("2019-03-03") AND DATE_ADD('2019-03-04',INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```